# I'm getting my masters in cybersecurity and I have a bs in criminal justice... need guidance

Tags: investigation

I'm getting my masters in cyber security. I have a bachelors in criminal justice. I would like to do missing and exploited children investigation. I'm relocating to Georgia. What kind of job should I apply for?

Comment: Georgia the state or Georgia the country?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Answer (score 2):

If you are relocating to Georgia the state, then your best bet is probably the FBI.  They tend to be the ones who handle most of that kind of stuff since it could cross state lines and it has always been a real soft spot of theirs that they care a lot about.  I'd recommend a special agent position, though you might be able to get something in their professional support roles.

There are a couple of tricks with special agents though.  You have to be able to pass a physical fitness test, they only hire periodically (about once a year) and they move you wherever they need you (they let you choose 10 places you'd like to work and 90% of the time or so they can give you one of those).  You also have to be at least 23 and while they normally want 3 years work experience, I think they may waive that part for people with a masters, and you are right up the alley of the kind of people they need badly right now.

Comment: As an aside, this is probably going to end up closed as off topic, but I answered because I also have a soft spot for this area.  If you'd like to talk more offline, my contact info is aj at [myusername] dot com (ie, aj(at)ajh..... dot com.

Comment: @LucasKauffman - no, the female body inspectors are the TSA, the acronyms just got switched at birth.